# How do you recreate a remote link with the same .js update in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Basically I want to make a link able to be refreshed dynamically from "Favorited" to "Removed", and at the same time give the user the option to go go back by reclicking the new button.  The action does happen though, because when I refresh the page the updated button shows. Why does clicking the "Favorite this Classroom" link not work?  The "Remove this Classroom" link seems to work. Thanks for your help

favorites_controller.rb:

```
  def create
    current_classroom.add_to_favorites(@classroom)
    current_classroom.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {  }
      format.html {redirect_to @classroom}
    end
  end

  def destroy
    current_classroom.remove_from_favorites(@classroom)
    current_classroom.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {  }
      format.html {redirect_to @classroom}
    end
  end
```

favorites/create.js.erb

```
$("#favorite_classroom").html("<%= escape_javascript(link_to 'Remove the Classroom', classroom_favorite_path(@classroom), :remote => true, :method => :delete) %>");
```

classrooms/_classroom_details.html.erb

```
<div id="favorite_classroom">
<% if loggedin_user.favorite_classroom?(@classroom) %>
    <%= link_to 'Remove this Classroom', classroom_favorite_path(@classroom), :remote => true, :method => :delete %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to 'Favorite this Classroom', classroom_favorites_path(@classroom), :remote => true, :method => :post %>
<% end %>
```

routes:

```
classroom_favorites POST   /classrooms/:classroom_id/favorites(.:format)  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"favorites"}
classroom_favorite DELETE /classrooms/:classroom_id/favorites/:id(.:format) {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"favorites"}
```

Error when I click on the "Favorite this Classroom" link:
`ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"favorites"`

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you sure need a `destroy` method on your controller. If you have one, can you please show us?

Comment: Sorry, accidentally removed it from the question. Put it back into the SO question.

Comment: I believe you have a `destroy.js.erb` too, that does the same thing as the create one. The only thing i can advise you is to remove the inner html of the `#favorite_classroom` div before appending the new content again. Something like this: `$('@favorite_classroom').children().remove()`.

Comment: @MurifoX - I'm using jQuery's html function which I believe replaces all of the html in the #favorite_classroom div so I wouldn't need to remove anything.  Please correct me if I'm wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

You are using double-quotes **twice** in your js file. You can't do that. You need to rewrite it like this -

```
$("#favorite_classroom").html("<%= escape_javascript(link_to 'Remove the Classroom', classroom_favorite_path(@classroom), :remote => true, :method => :delete) %>");
```

Notice now that Remove the Classroom is enclosed in single quotes rather than double.

In addition, your route is incorrect because you have nested favorites within classrooms. When you write the link, you need to add the @favorite object that you are trying to delete:

```
= link_to 'Remove Favorite', classroom_favorite_path([@classroom, @favorite]), :remote => true, :method => :delete
```

Now the route you are trying to access is valid. That should get rid of the error.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my question with that information. The internal 500 error isn't coming up anymore. I've also removed the double quotes but the "Favorite a Classroom" still doesn't work.  It gives a routing error that I've added to my question above.

Comment: Sending in two objects to the `classroom_favorite_path` does not work.  In terms of data structure, there is no separate table for favorites bc an array of ids representing classrooms exists as a field in the User table.  All thats needed is @classroom and we know the logged in user.

Comment: @Goalie well if you don't have a separate table for favorites, and they are stored as id's in the users table you can't use RESTful routes and Rails' delete methods and expect them to work. Rails is: convention over configuration. You need to follow the REST rules, otherwise things will not (and should not) work. The issues you are experiencing have nothing to do with the links etc and everything to do with the way you set up your models and data structure.

Comment: One thing that might be important that I didn't want to mention to complicate things is we are using mongoDB which is different than what most RoR applications use. This might have something to do with this.

Comment: @Goalie the db you are using doesn't affect this. The issue is that you are trying to use default RESTful routes without an underlying favorites table. It doesn't work like that. You need to create custom routes do to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the favorite controller, what you need is favorite/unfavorite action for classroom controller. Here's how it might look

**classroom_controller.rb**

```
respond_to :html, :js

def favorite
  # ... find classroom by id
  # do your stuff
  @classroom.favorite = !@classroom.favorite
  respond_with(@classroom)
end
```

**views/classrooms/favorite.js.erb**

```
<%# the message should be oposite to favorite %>
<% msg = @classroom.favorite ? "Remove this Classroom" : "Favorite this Classroom" %>
$("#favorite_classroom").html("<%= escape_javascript(link_to msg, [:favorite, @classroom], :remote => true) %>");
```

Here's the trick with path helper, `[:favorite, @classroom]` should be transleted to `/classrooms/:id/favorite`. If it won't work then try `favorite_classrooms_path(@classroom)`

And finally add to your **routes.rb**

```
resource :classrooms do 
  member { get :favorite }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to reference 'favorite_id' in your link to match your routes.

In your case, would probably be:

```
classroom_favorite_path([current_classroom, @classroom])
```